# how to put quotation marks around several words simultaneously in chrome inspector

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I was watching a video that showed a column of words in chrome inspector / sources/ snippets. The words were all selected and got surrounded simultaneously by double quotes. How was it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks

"Column (box) selection

You can select blocks of text by holding Shift+Alt (Shift+Option on macOS) while you drag your mouse. A separate cursor will be added to the end of each selected line."

It also works in Chrome inspector. When selected, adding quotes added quotes to the beginning and end of every line selected.